# Clicking on an unselectable td within a table

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

[image]

I need help clicking on `"Fonds"` using `Selenium`.

I've tried the following:

1. Using `XPath`:

   ```
   IWebElement baseTable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("id_popup_NEW_div"));
   baseTable.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[./td[text()='Fonds']]")).Click();
   ```

> *An exception of type **'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException'** occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Cannot click on element*

2. Using an `Action`:

   ```
   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   IWebElement we = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[./td[text()='Fonds']]"));
   action.MoveToElement(we).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[./td[text()='Fonds']]"))).Click().Build().Perform();
   ```

But the `we` does not find any text associated with that element.

Note: The `td` has an `unselectable` property, that is why I am trying to go with an `Action` (mouse over).

Comment: Please provide some of the html for the object you're trying to click. My guess is you'll need to click some outer element that contains `Fonds` and is visible, or you'll need to wait for it to become visible before attempting a `click()`

Comment: If the `html` is in that image, please add the text, some like me can't see external images from their networks :) cheers!

Comment: Remove the unselected attribute and then it will be clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the unselectable attribute completely before you attempt to click it:

```
public void removeAttributeFromElement(WebElement element){
        String strJavaScript = "arguments[0].removeAttribute('unselectable'); return arguments[0];";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) yourSeleniumWebDriver).executeScript(strJavaScript, element);
    }
```